# Get Firebase Function current region

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Does anyone know why FUNCTION_REGION environment variable was dropped?

I am trying to deploy functions across regions, each function working with local resources (firestore, other local resources/services).

```
export const admin =  functions
    .region("us-central1", "europe-west2")
    .https.onRequest(app);
```

To be able to lookup the right config I need to figure out the current region.
Is there any way to get the current region from a firebase function?

How do people do this and why it's not a very common question? What am I missing?

*Update:* It's FUNCTION_REGION I was looking for not FIREBASE_REGION(not a variable)

Answer (score 3):

I have never heard of it being populated in the first place, so it might be the case that you were depending on an undocumented implementation detail.  The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#automatically_populated_environment_variables) today doesn't suggest anything about the region being available in the environment.

If you have a question about **why** there was an apparent change, I'd send that question to the Firebase team directly, either through [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) or the [firebase-talk](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/firebase-talk) group.

If you want to detect the region at runtime, the [Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#environment_variables_set_automatically) says that you can use FUNCTION_REGION when targeting the node 8 runtime.  It's not clear how best to do that on node 10.  Perhaps you can parse it out of the URL the client used to invoke the function.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I was looking at the google functions docs: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#nodejs_6_nodejs_8_python_37_and_go_111

FUNCTION_REGION was present in nodejs 6 and 8.
I don't want to depend on parsing the host header to get the region.

I'll probably set environment variables on the functions myself.